# Handle Dynamic Nodes in soapUI

Tags: soapui

I am getting a response from webservice like this,for the first input it is giving me three nodes like this

```
        <m:tPlayerNames>
           <m:iId>16</m:iId>
           <m:sName>Adam Matuszczyk</m:sName>
           <m:sCountryName>Poland</m:sCountryName>
        </m:tPlayerNames>
        <m:tPlayerNames>
           <m:iId>588</m:iId>
           <m:sName>Adil Rami</m:sName>
           <m:sCountryName>France</m:sCountryName>
         </m:tPlayerNames>
```

For the second input I am getting more than two tPlayerNames Nodes  ,like this

```
        <m:tPlayerNames>
           <m:iId>16</m:iId>
           <m:sName>Adam Matuszczyk</m:sName>
           <m:sCountryName>Poland</m:sCountryName>
        </m:tPlayerNames>
        <m:tPlayerNames>
           <m:iId>588</m:iId>
           <m:sName>Adil Rami</m:sName>
           <m:sCountryName>France</m:sCountryName>
         </m:tPlayerNames>
        <m:tPlayerNames>
           <m:iId>552</m:iId>
           <m:sName>Zlatan Ibrahimovic</m:sName>
           <m:sCountryName>Sweden</m:sCountryName>
        </m:tPlayerNames>
```

I want to add the assertion for each node and I am doing data driven testing and I am not sure about number of nodes for each request so how I can do this this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a groovy script to parse the XML. since you do not know the exact response before creating the assertion. Here below you can find a script to parse a xml response and find an element

```
def response = context.expand( '${Test Request#Response#declare namespace soap=\'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\'; //soap:Envelope[1]}' )
def responseParser = new XmlParser().parseText(response)
def allNodes = responseParser.children()

def nodeToFind=responseParser.nodeOfResponse.find { it.text() == 'text' }

log.info nodeToFind
```